# Like Operator to retrieve the results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a record in the database table with Street_Name "Park Avenue 10" in Street table.

I want to retrieve the record like

```
SELECT *
  FROM Street
 WHERE Street_Name LIKE '%Park Ave 10%'
```

The current like operator does not give the result "Park Avenue 10" for the above query.

How can I split the word with spaces and check the like operator for each word to get "Park Avenue 10" in MSSQLSERVER

Comment: have you tried with `like '%Park Ave% 10'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select * from Street where Street_Name like REPLACE('%Park Ave 10%',' ', '%')
```

Answer (score 2):

If it will be in the same order `Park` then `Ave` then `10` then you can use

```
Select * from Street where Street_Name like '%Park%Ave%10%'
```

else

```
Select * from Street where Street_Name like '%Park%' and  Street_Name like '%Ave%' and Street_Name like '%10%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from Street where Street_Name like '%Park%Ave%10%'
```

this will help.

for more details refer this
[Link](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A85397_01/operator.htm#997970)